# All about \shipout

Tags: macros, tex-core, hooks, output-routine

While reading about packages that allow to *hook* macros to certain events, I came across this command, `\shipout`. Searching on the internet didn't help a lot but if I'm not so wrong it's somehow related to creating new pages (or is it?).

My question is, what is exactly `\shipout`, what does it do and how it does what it does? (i.e. what is happening on the low-level in the background)

Comment: `\shipout` is apparently primitive, because `\show\shipout` produces `> \shipout=\shipout.`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is quite easy: `\shipout` is a primitive. Its syntax is

> \shipout ⟨box⟩

where ⟨box⟩ is completely specified at page 278 of the TeXbook:

> ⟨box⟩ → `\box`⟨8-bit number⟩ | `\copy`⟨8-bit number⟩
>     | `\lastbox` | `\vsplit`⟨8-bit number⟩ `to` ⟨dimen⟩
>     | `\hbox`⟨box specification⟩`{`⟨horizontal mode material⟩`}`
>     | `\vbox`⟨box specification⟩`{`⟨vertical mode material⟩`}`
>     | `\vtop`⟨box specification⟩`{`⟨vertical mode material⟩`}`
>   ⟨box specification⟩ → `to` ⟨dimen⟩⟨filler⟩ | `spread` ⟨dimen⟩⟨filler⟩ | ⟨filler⟩

One could, for example, say

```
\shipout\hbox{Hello world}
```

and one page in the DVI or PDF file will be created. Of course nobody wants to use `\shipout` this way. Its main usage is in the output routine that is called when TeX decides it has sufficient material for ejecting a full page. The current main vertical list is split at the chosen page break and its contents is packaged into `\box255`, which the output routine can act on. For example, the Plain TeX output routine does

```
\shipout\vbox{
  \makeheadline
  \pagebody
  \makefootline
}
\advancepageno
\ifnum\outputpenalty>-\@MM
\else
  \dosupereject
\fi
```

so a full page, adorned with headers and footers is shipped out. The contents of `\box255` is massaged by `\pagebody`. The output routine in LaTeX is much more complicated.

What one can do is redefining `\shipout` so it does other jobs. The oldest macro set that did something like this was `quire.tex` (still available on CTAN and TeX Live)

```
\def\q_init
   {\global\q_sheetnr=0\global\q_qnr=0
    \global\let\q_oldship=\shipout
    \global\let\shipout=\q_boat
    \xdef\q_cycles{\the\deadcycles}%
    \global\let\endquire=\q_endquire
   }
```

It saves the primitive meaning of `\shipout` in the command `\q_oldship` (the macros use `_` as a ‘private’ marker) and redefines it to be `\q_boat`, which will do some jobs and eventually call `\q_oldship`. For instance it could be set up for placing two output pages on the same physical page, or for making sixteen page quires (whence the package name).

The package `atbegshi` does similarly. It redefines `\shipout` so that it can hook between the call of `\shipout` and the actual page ship out.

What precisely the primitive `\shipout` does is transforming the vertical list it's fed with into low level printing instructions (DVI or PDF format, according to the value of `\pdfoutput` if `pdftex` or `luatex` is used, XDV if `xetex` is used, only DVI for Knuth TeX). Meanwhile it executes all delayed `\write` operations, expanding tokens as it goes: in this way references to the page number are guaranteed to be correct, because they are computed when the page is being shipped out.

Answer (score 11):

From *TeXbook*, Chapter 23: Output Routines, page 254:

> TeX’s primitive command `\shipout`<box> is what actually causes output. It sends the contents of the box to the `dvi` file, which is TeX’s main output file; after TeX has finished, the `dvi` file will contain a compact device-independent encoding of instructions that specify exactly what should be printed. When a box is shipped out, TeX displays the values of `\count0` through `\count9` on your terminal, as explained in Chapter 15; these ten counters are also recorded in the `dvi` file, where they can be used to identify the page. All of the `\openout`, `\closeout`, and `\write` commands that appear inside of the box are performed in their natural order as that box is being shipped out. Since a `\write` command expands macros, as explained in Chapter 21, TeX’s scanning mechanism might detect syntax errors while a `\shipout` is in progress. If `\tracingoutput` is nonzero at the time of a `\shipout`, the contents of the box being shipped are written into your log file in symbolic form. You can say `\shipout` anywhere, not only in an output routine.